# How to set proper buffersize of AudioRecord

Tags: android, buffer, record, audiorecord

I use `AudioRecord` to record audio on Android device. To create a instance of `AudioRecord`, you should set a fixed size of `buffer` to store the audio data. Then, we need pull data from this `buffer` continuously. If the size of `buffer` is too small and fetching data is too slow, the `buffer` will be overflow !
To avoid this exception, I want to set the size of `buffer` larger as far as possible and fetching data in time.
`AudioRecord` provides the `getMinBufferSize(int,int,int)` method to get a min size of `buffer` that audio hardware can support. But this is mininum size not the proper size of `buffer`.

My question is how to calculate and set the proper size of the `buffer`?

Here is what I using the `AudioRecord`:

```
audioRecord = new AudioRecord(audio_source, sampleRate, audio_channel, audio_encoding, buffer_size);
new Thread(new Runnable{
    while(true){ //Loop start
        readSize = audioRecorder.read(readBuffer, 0, useReadBufferSize); // fetch data from  buffer to readbuffer
        // throw readbuffer data out, do this operation as qucik as possible, Avoid to block thread
        // check if the AudioRecord stopped and break if true
    }
}).start();
```